# Asking another Question in a Self Answer

Tags: discussion

In this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491527/closest-matching-on-multiple-axis) the OP answered with  a solution but asked for another question in the answer. I commented that he should edit the question to include the relevant parts of the answer and make the title more relevant. Then delete the answer.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most things it's essentially a judgement call.

In this *particular* instance I agree with you that the OP has essentially updated the question in an answer there. As such, the information should be moved into the question and the answer deleted.

**However**, imagine the answer had been this:

> I figured it out. I need a k-d tree, where k = 8.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree
>
> I implemented it with the following code:
>
> ```
> <some code>
> ```
>
> I'd still prefer an out of the box NoSQL implementation, if one is available.

That's an answer to the question, with a little comment on the end to state that the question is not *completely* answered.

Comment: @WillNess read both answers again.

Comment: @WillNess I figured it out. I need a k-d tree, where k = 8.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree IS NOT AN ACCEPTABLE ANSWER ----I figured it out. I need a k-d tree, where k = 8.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

I implemented it with the following code:

<some code> IS

Comment: @davidstrachan ahh, I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; that is exactly what most of us would do!

<sub>Well, that was some question there :/</sub>

---

Alternatively; you can flag the reply as it is basically just a link to external source.